# TypeError: expected numeric

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have one model with the name `job`.

I want to calculate the number of days since the `job` has been created.

I think we have to calculate the difference between `Date.today` and `jobs` `created_at`

my method is:

```
def self.open_jobs(date)
    Date.today - where("status='open' AND date(created_at) = ?",date).round
end
```

I am getting some error please let me know how to calculate the days the job has been created.

I have to calculate number of days. for example I have created a job on 20th sep 2012.
it should be Date.today - 20/09/2013
answer should be 5 days and one more thing i need to check one more column status ="open" and display only those jobs.

if anybody knows how to calculate please post here.

Comment: please see my answer, however the method in your question seems aimed at a different outcome than what you're question is asking - what is it that you're looking  for?

Answer (score 16):

`job.created_at` is a `Time`, `Date.today` is a `Date`

You can't subtract `Time` and `Date`. See that `Date.tomorrow - Time.now` gives you that error.

To get the difference in seconds:

```
Time.now - job.created_at
```

You can convert this to days (float or integer) as follows:

```
(Time.now - job.created_at) / 24.hours
((Time.now - job.created_at) / 24.hours).to_i
```

Alternately there is (MyGod's answer):

```
Date.today.mjd - job.created_at.to_date.mjd
```

Comment: The third response is exactly what i need. Thx

Answer (score 1):

You're right that you should use `Date.today` and `job.created_at`

If you want to calculate the number of days since the job has been created use this:

```
def job_for_days
  (Date.today - self.created_at).round(1.day)
end
```

Comment: but i am getting undefined method self and one more thing i need check one more column job.status='open' how to write method for this?

Comment: did you put this method in the `job` model?  as for the second question, please see my comment on your original post

Answer (score 1):

Given two dates-

```
date1= Date.parse("10/10/2012")

date2= Date.parse("10/21/2012")
```

The difference in days:

```
date2.mjd - date1.mjd
```

where,

mjd  = Modified Julian Day Number